# Ng-click and ng-repeat - angularJs doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know about different scopes inside ng-repeat, I headed about this but I still can't solute removing of selected item of li ( I don't use $index ) instead of future sortable objects

```
<li class="m-1" ng-repeat="students in students.students">
  <span>{{students.student}}</span> :knowledge is - <span>{{students.knowledge}}</span>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger ml-2" ng-click="students.removeItem(item)">Delete</button>
</li>
```

and my function working behind li-element, but delete only last element

```
vm.removeItem = function (item) {
  vm.students.splice(vm.students.indexOf(item), 1);
}
```

and I don't need $parent in ng-repeat

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are trying to do something like:

```
<li class="m-1" ng-repeat="student in students.students">
  <span>{{student.name}}</span> :knowledge is - <span>{{student.knowledge}} </span>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger ml-2" ng- click="removeItem(student)">Delete</button>
</li>

$scope.removeItem = function (item) {
    this.students.students = this.students.students.filter(student => student !== item)
};
```

This is a [working demo](https://codepen.io/alonsh/pen/BGaVGB?editors=1010)

Honestly, I don't understand why you have students object in students.
In addition, why every item in ng-repeat is called: students?

I guess that every item needs the variable name of `student`.

Comment: my code like this: https://codepen.io/Pavlolapan/pen/qQByWM?editors=1010
I never use codepen and it doesn't even display a arr. list

Comment: https://codepen.io/alonsh/pen/WYNapV?editors=1010

Please accept my answer if it works